# Background worker for android studio "this" parameter error

Tags: android, server, backgroundworker

The initialize my background worker I use this code. BackgroundWorker is a class.
For some reason the "this" says 'can not be applied'.

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
```

===more code from that area===

```
    mApp.setListener(new OAuthAuthenticationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

            // tvSummary.setText("Connected as " + mApp.getUserName());
            btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");
            llAfterLoginView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // userInfoHashmap = mApp.
            mApp.fetchUserName(handler);
        }
        public void OnLogin() {

            String username = "hi";
            String password = "hi";
            String type = "register";
            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this); // <-- that one
            backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

===Worker===

https://pastebin.com/rMZqvvhF

The code above is the class the hold the BackgroundWorker. In this class. It connects and adds or logins to the server. I am very new so I would appreciate help.

=========EDIT (additional help)=========

Thank you guys for all the help, but I have an issue. When I change this to getApplicationData, it runs the background worker but then crashes the app. Any Ideas?

=========EDIT========

It looks like your Backgroundworker takes in a Context for the constructor. Instead of using "this", try using getApplicationContext() to get the context instead.

Comment: Is BackgroundWorker a standard library class? I don't see docs online for it

Comment: I it a java class I made

Comment: If I am completely wrong. Please lead me in how to accomplish this task

Comment: If BackgroundWorker is a class you wrote, how can anyone tell you why it doesn't work if you don't provide its source code?

Comment: good point one sec

Comment: Is OAuthAuthenticationListener also a custom class? Does it derive from Context?

Comment: Under which class does     mApp.setListener() is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` in your example refer on `OAuthAuthenticationListener` not `Activity`. So use something like that:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(getBaseContext());
```

If your code is inside `Fragment` so use `getContext()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Backgroundworker takes in a Context for the constructor. Instead of using "this", try using getApplicationContext() to get the context instead.